# Pick Contacts starting from a specific alphabet from phone contact list in android studio

Tags: android, android-contacts

As the title says, I want to select contacts list from the phone contacts which start from the given alphabet.
for example: if i want to select only the contacts starting with A, my current code which i tried is:

```
val selecteContactsList: ArrayList<SelectedContactItem> = arrayListOf()
val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        ),
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?",
        arrayOf("A"),
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
    )

    while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
        val contactName =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
        val contactNumber =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
        val contactItem = SelectedContactItem(contactNumber, contactName)
        selecteContactsList.add(contactItem)
    }
    cursor.close()
```

But this does not give any output. total selected contacts count is 0.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your app have the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, including requesting it at runtime? If you remove the `+ " = ?"` part, do you get the full list of contacts? Bear in mind that there is no requirement for `ContactsContract` to understand `+ " = ?"` syntax.

Comment: yes, i have added READ_CONTACTS permission in the manifest and also made sure that the user has given the permission before accessing them.

Comment: @CommonsWare after removing { + " = ? "}, i am getting error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.

Comment: Sorry, you would also need to replace `arrayOf("A")` with `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare but if i want to select only the contacts starting with A, don't i need to pass the value "A" somewhere?

Comment: You would filter those out in your Kotlin code. Note that even if `ContactsContract` on a device *happens* to be backed by something that understands SQL syntax, `" = ?"` is equality, not starts-with. Filtering your results in your application is the most reliable approach to doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the part:

```
Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?",
arrayOf("A"),
```

means 'return all contacts with name A'.

I think you want to ask 'return all contacts with name starting with the letter A' which is a different query.

To do that you can change the code to:

```
Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE 'A%'"
```

If you want a case insensitive query (i.e. include names that begin with small 'a'), try:

```
Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE 'A%' COLLATE NOCASE"
```

However, if your goal is to show a list of all contacts, and have a scroller sidebar where the user can touch the letter "C" and jump to contact names beginning with that letter I would not suggest to have such queries, instead query for **all** contacts on the device, and show them all in one big scrollable list, and have those letters buttons scroll to a certain position in the list when touched.

The user experience would be far superior.

Comment: I found "Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE 'A%'" this solution during my research. but thanks a lot for "Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE 'A%' COLLATE NOCASE". this solved the second problem which I was facing. cheers